# Is there any built-in function to eliminate diagonal zeros?

Tags: matlab, matrix

Consider a matrix as follows:

```
A=   4     0    31     1     0     0
     0     0     0    -1     1    11
     0     0     0    24    -1     0
     2     1     0     0    17    -3
    27     2     0     0     1     1
     3    12     0    -1     0     0
```

Now I need to perform Jacobi iterations (The problem is that some of the diagonal elements are zero). Therefore, I need to perform some matrix transformations e.g. row operations to covert this matrix into a new one such that the diagonal elements become non-zero and the determinant of the newly formed matrix should be same as A. Is there any way to do this in Matlab?

Comment: Your question does not have a unique answer. If there is such a function, it should have more restricting conditions to make the answer unique.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that A is full rank, you can use QR decomposition (Matlab `qr` function).

```
[Q,R] = qr(A)
```

[From the Matlab documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/qr.html), we know that `R` is upper-triangular, `Q` is unitary, and `A = Q * R`.

Because `R` is an upper-triangular matrix, it is ideal for solution and back-substitution. Its diagonal elements will be non-zero if `A` is full rank (and if `A` is singular, there may be no matrix meeting your requirements).

Using `A = Q * R`, therefore `Q' * A = Q' * Q * R` but since `Q` is unitary, then `R = Q' * A`. Thus `Q'` describes the row operations you need to perform, and `R` is the resulting matrix with non-zero diagonal. Also, because `|det(Q)| = 1` (a consequence of being unitary), then `|det(A)| = |det(R)|`.  To resolve a sign mismatch, you can negate one row.

Comment: The operation of diag(eigen(A)) doesn't work for me as I have a lower version of Matlab (2012a). Is there any other way to do so?

Comment: @Soumya: From `[Q,R] = qr(A)`, `R` is an upper-triangular matrix, ideal for solution and back-substitution.  Its diagonal elements will be non-zero if `A` is full rank (and if `A` is singular, there may be no matrix meeting your requirements).  Also, `A = Q * R` and therefore `Q' * A = Q' * Q * R` but since `Q` is unitary, then `R = Q' * A`.  Thus `Q'` are the row operations you need to perform, and `R` is the resulting matrix with non-zero diagonal.  Also, because`det(Q) = 1`, then `det(A) = det(R)`.

Comment: Thanks. I got the idea and found R also. But det(Q)= -1; Should I need to adjust it to R or have I done anything wrong?

Comment: Hmm, I guess `det(Q) = -1` is possible.  If you multiply the last row of `R`  (which is all zeros except the diagonal entry) by `-1` then I guess you should have `det(A) = det(R)` again.  I think that should be an allowed Jacobi operation...

Comment: Yes I've done it. But when I try to verify the solution for Matrix R, I find that it's not the solution for the original Matrix A i.e. The equation Ax=b when converted to Rx=b does not give the same solution for x (A\b !=R\b). Where am I wrong?

Comment: @Soumya: In Jacobi iterations, you have to do the same operations on `b`.  I.e. `A*x=b` so `Q*R*x=b` so `Q'*Q*R*x=Q'*b` and finally `R*x = Q'*b`  This last one is easy to solve because `R` is triangular; use backsubstitution.

Comment: Many many thanks... By the way, I proceeded with det(Q)= -1 and got the desired result.